# Ip Config Not Reloaded

Tags: raspbian, ifconfig

My ifconfig :

```
eth0 ....
     inet addr:192.168.1.180

eth0:1 ...
     inet addr:10.1.0.180
```

My `/etc/networks`

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static 
address 10.1.0.180
```

I do `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

But ifconfig tells me that nothing is changed: same interfaces and same IP!

Comment: What are you expecting to change exactly?

Comment: I expect that the IP of eth0 be 10.1.0.180 and no alias

Answer (score 0):

On Debian - and probably many other distributions - the file `/etc/networks` is for a totally different purpose (it gives network subnets well known names). Here is mine:

```
default         0.0.0.0
loopback        127.0.0.0
link-local      169.254.0.0
```

Perhaps you intended to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` instead?

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static 
        address 10.1.0.180
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.1.0.255
```

You should provide a `netmask` as well as just `address`. The `gateway` is optional but if you want to go off-net you'll need it. If you have the `resolvconf` package installed you can also use the `dns-nameserver` and `dns-search` elements.

To remove the alias so that networking can reassign the IP addresses you may need to handle that manually:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 down
ifconfig eth0 down
service networking restart
```

Comment: I added your answer snippet in /etc/network/interfaces  ...not work after retarting networking

Comment: still not working. Maybe I should note that the debian is actually a raspbian? Or it does not matter?

Comment: In the file you mentioned, there is clearly written "Please note that this file is written to be used with dhpcd"

Comment: @giuseppe yes it would help if you correctly identified the OS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

1) `/etc/hosts` contained an entry

```
192.168.1.180 raspberry
```

I deleted it and now it works

2) Check if the `dhclient` is keeping requesting IPv6 addresses to IPv6 routers. I switched off that in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and did a `sysctrl -p`